# Наложение background только на текст

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, svg

Есть текст. На него надо наложить `background` так, чтобы он был только на тексте. То есть все, что не текст, было прозрачным. Думаю через `svg` сделать наложение картинки на текст, но не знаю, как сделать все прозрачным, кроме букв. Сложность в том, что на каждой букве должны быть не разные картинки, а одна цельная

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```css
svg {
  width: 6em;
  height: 1.5em;
  font: 900 500%/1.2 'Arial Black', sans-serif;
}

text {
  fill: url(#sea);
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <pattern id="sea" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="544" height="340" >
      <image xlink:href="http://i01.i.aliimg.com/wsphoto/v0/32244527293/F0050-24inch-x38-inch-Underwater-World-Coral-Sharks-Turtle-Moray-Eel-Fish-Poster-on-Waterproof-Canvas.jpg" width="544" height="340" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <text y="1.2em">Ваш текст!!!</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: искал ваш старый ответ по закраске изображений. Заодно просмотрел другие  ваши ответы, многое понравилось.

Comment: @Alexandr_T, (ง ื▿ ื)ว

Answer (score 10):

Обратите внимание на проблему кроссбраузерности.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  font: 900 normal 450%/100vh sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN1F6.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum</div>
```