# Как сверстать такие элементы (текст, через буквы которого видна картинка; кнопка, внутри неё стрелка, которая выходит за границу кнопки)?

Tags: html, css, frontend, layout

Всем доброго времени суток!

Как сверстать такие элементы:

1. Первые буквы текста другим цветом выделены (логотип Active Trust)
2. Текст, через символы которого видна картинка (Заголовок Active Trust идёт после "Digital-агенство")
3. Неполное подчёркивание Заголовка Active Trust (вроде border-bottom не подходит).
4. Текст, загнутый в круг, через символы которого видная картинка (во втором блоке Digital-агенство Active Trust)
5. Кнопка, внутри которой картинка или символ стрелки, конец которой выходит за пределы этой кнопки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. 

```css
body {
 background-color: black
}

.logo {
 color: white;
}

.logo span{
 color: blue
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
<span>A</span>ctive<br>
<span>T</span>rust
</div>
```

2. Наложение background изображения на текст обсудили вот тут - [Наложение background только на текст](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/697436/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-background-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82)
3. 

```css
.someText {
 font-size: 30px;
 position: relative
}

.someText:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -10px;
 left: 0;
 width: 100px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="someText">Любой длинный большой заголовок чтобы показать линию</div>
```

4. Текст по кругу можно посмотреть вот тут вот - [Как сделать текст по контуру круга?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1116528/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%83-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0) + комбинировать с ссылкой в пункте 2
5. 

```css
body {
 padding: 100px
}

.btn {
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 position: relative;
 background-color: black;
}

.btn:after {
 content: 'любой элемент';
 position: absolute;
 left: -30px;
 top: 2px;
 color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn"></div>
```